# Visual Studio 2022 - Just My Code debugging not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm using VS 2022 and no matter what setting I change, I can't get the thing to stop trying to step into compiled dependencies.  I have an exception that is occurring that gets swallowed up and this is presented:

[image]

I've tried resetting my C# settings for VS22 and I've ensured Just My Code is enabled.

[image]

Comment: I am also having this problem. Exceptions are being thrown all over the place outside my code and it oftens asks me to find the source as well, yet my code actually works just fine. As an example, I have a number of v1 and v3 Azure Functions. Under VS 2019 they just start. Under VS 2022 I get exceptions about null values and not being able to find "function.json". Tried all sorts, can't stop it and it's making debugging very tiresome.

Comment: Ditto. It's as if, once "Enable Just My Code" has been unchecked, it will never re-enable it.

Comment: Resetting the settings in visual studio is the only solution that worked for me. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2022

Comment: I tried resetting also it is not working however when I create new project it is working but for old project still debugger is not hitting

Comment: I tried too. No joy.  Anyone have a working answer?

Comment: i tried resettings settings and didnt work, some projects still were debugging framework code. I manually deleted everything inside my project\bin\ folder, that worked.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround, select **"Load only specified modules"** and click on **"Specify included modules"**. Either leave the list empty or make sure the module VS is attempting to debug is not listed there.

[image]

It seems if symbols have been loaded for an external library, Visual Studio would ignore *"Enable just my code"* and still attempting to debug that library, which is really annoying.

Comment: I can't seem to remove the external modules it has already downloaded before enabling this option, did you experience that?

Answer (score 4):

The first time you uncheck "Enable Just My Code" under options - Debugging - General, the box will be greyed out and you will be UNABLE to re-check the box. Because Microsoft :D

[image: General]

However, there is a fix for this that doesn't include resetting the whole IDE settings, as some have suggested.

Go to Debugging - Symbols, and click on "Load only specified modules" radio button. Then click on "Specify included modules" below and be sure that there are no modules selected there.

[image: Symbols]

Then, press OK and RESTART visual studio.

After VS has restarted, go to options - Debugging - General and now you'll be able to re-check "Enable Just My Code".

It's a bit ridiculous, but that's the best way to do it.

Comment: Worked for me. Nuts that they disabled "Enabled Just my code" when you disable it once.

Answer (score 0):

**Viperus**' answer was almost enough for me to make it, I upvoted his answer.
In my case, there were no issues checking and unchecking the `Enable Just My Code` flag, but it brought no result.
I had to uncheck it, go through the steps **Viperus** wrote, and then check it back (without the `Warn if no user code on launch (Managed only)` option). This way, it stopped showing me `Find cs file` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties under build you can find the optimize code option
Make sure optimize code is unchecked.

Answer (score -5):

Step 1: Click on Tools and click on Options.
Step 2: On Debugging General Uncheck Enable Just My Code.

[image]

Step 3: check both Symbol Servers.
[image]

Step 4: Restart the Visual Studio.

Comment: "Just My Code debugging not working?" As in "not" working.